# puzzling routing issue - Packets not forwarded between public interface and VM with nested VM's

Tags: networking, vmware, routing, vmware-workstation

Here is my somewhat puzzling routing problem.

[image: graphical representation]

Here's the description, in words. I have a windows laptop (blue) on which I run VMWare Workstation (orange). VMWare Workstation has a single Ubuntu 14.04 VM (Green). It has a single NIC which is a VMWare NAT interface. VMWare has an interface on the network as seen from windows (ipconfig output). The VMWare VM (green) has an IP of 192.168.115.10/24. The windows interface (gateway) is 192.168.115.1.

Within the Green VM, I have a red VM (KVM). It has an IP address of 10.0.0.2.

Here are the things that work.

From Windows:

- ping 192.168.115.1: Works
- ping 192.168.115.10: Works
- ssh 192.168.115.10: Works
- ping www.google.com: Works

From Green VM (192.168.115.10) the following work.

- ping 192.168.115.1: Works
- ping 192.168.115.10: Works
- ping 10.0.0.2: Works
- ping www.google.com: Works

From the Red VM (10.0.0.2) the following work.

- ping 192.168.115.1: Works
- ping 192.168.115.10: Works
- ping 10.0.0.2: Works
- ping www.google.com: Works

What doesn't work is this:

- From Windows, ping 10.0.0.2.

On Green VM (192.168.115.10), I have enabled IP forwarding.

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
```

On Windows machine, I have a routing table entry that reads:

```
Active Routes: Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway    
Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0        10.40.2.1      10.40.2.192     10
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0        10.40.2.1      10.40.2.186     25
         10.0.0.0    255.255.255.0   192.168.115.10    192.168.115.1     21 [...]
```

I've also done this.

On Green VM, and Red VM, simultaneously run tcpdump.

> tcpdump -n -vvv -i **eth0** icmp

And while this is running, from Windows execute:

> ping 10.0.0.2

On Green VM (192.168.115.10), I see

```
21:48:45.985686 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 9541, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 60)
     192.168.115.1 > 10.0.0.2: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 145, length 40 21:48:50.987085 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 9543, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 60)
     192.168.115.1 > 10.0.0.2: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 146, length 40
```

On Red VM (10.0.0.2) I see nothing.

On the other hand, if I ran ping on 192.168.115.10 (ping 10.0.0.2), I see the following in tcpdump.

On Green VM (192.168.115.10), I see the following on the interface br100, the one with an IP of 10.0.0.1 and the gateway to the nested VM.

```
tcpdump -n icmp -vvvv -i br100
tcpdump: listening on br100, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes 
22:16:35.310287 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 43787, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
     10.0.0.1 > 10.0.0.2: ICMP echo request, id 30901, seq 1, length 64 
22:16:35.310678 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 26368, offset 0, flags [none],  proto ICMP (1), length 84)
     10.0.0.2 > 10.0.0.1: ICMP echo reply, id 30901, seq 1, length 64
```

On Red VM (10.0.0.2) I see

```
tcpdump -vvv -n icmp 
tcpdump: listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes 
02:16:14.710411 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 42447, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
     10.0.0.1 > 10.0.0.2: ICMP echo request, id 30888, seq 1, length 64 
02:16:14.710690 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 21880, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
     10.0.0.2 > 10.0.0.1: ICMP echo reply, id 30888, seq 1, length 64
```

So, for some reason, when pinging from Windows, packets reach 192.168.115.10 (Green VM) and don't make it to 10.0.0.2 (Red VM).

I'm not sure what to look for in iptables, or maybe someplace else.

Comment: As a next step, I would try to route another address (for example the one for `www.google.com`) on Windows through `192.168.115.10` to distinguish between a general problem with routing on Green VM and a specific one to KVM and Red VM?

Comment: Sure looks like it works. On Windows I added this route. When I ping the IP, routing loop as expected.

172.217.4.68  255.255.255.255   192.168.115.10    192.168.115.1     21

06:29:25.987574 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 1251, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 60)
    192.168.115.1 > 172.217.4.68: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 161, length 40
[...]
06:29:26.001407 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 1, id 1314, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 60)
    192.168.115.1 > 172.217.4.68: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 161, length 40

Comment: How about completely disabling firewall on green and red?